# How to render html which is coming from php response

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, response

I am using codeigniter.
I am doing this in my front end code:-

```
$scope.book=function(){
 $http.get("./Booking/index")   //getting response as an html page, should render it to do correctly.
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);       //prints whole html code of booking.html
 });
}
```

And in my Booking controller I am doing:-

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('booking');
}
```

So I am getting as response as an html page [image: getting response as html page]

I want to render that html as the frontend code how can I do that? In simple words i want my book function when executed, gives up booking page as frontend which i am getting as response from get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which js framework you are using, so my answer is in bare javascript. Solution is to replace content of element in your page. You can do it like so

```
$scope.book=function(){
 $http.get("./Booking/index")  
    .then(function (data) {
      document.querySelector('.class_selector_or_#id_or_body').innerHTML = data;       
 });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you need to change you controller like this

```
public function index(){
    print_r($this->load->view('booking', '', TRUE));
}
```

and in your jquery change to this

```
$scope.book=function(){
 $http.get("./Booking/index")   //getting response as an html page, should render it to do correctly.
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('success');
      $("#some_div_id"),html(data);
 });
}
```

Comment: The OP definitely does not want to destroy the html using `print_r()`. And I'm not sure the OP is using jQuery either, this looks more like Angular.

Comment: refernce error: html is not defined, I added it as dependency but then i got injector module error.

Comment: @AsimRaja  use `$("#some_div_id").html(data)` is basic jQuery.